# TYPO3, Realurl, News and mutilanguage

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have a TYPO3 multilanguage site, and I am trying to configure Realurl and
News. Question is: for single/detailed News urls, how do I get both
speaking and language localized versions?

I mean, I am able to get:

```
localhost/it/paginaSingola/news/detail/News/titolo-singolo
localhost/en/singlePage/news/detail/News/single-title
```

but I wish something like:

```
all italian >> localhost/it/paginaSingola/notizie/singola/Notizie/titolo-singolo 
all english >> localhost/en/singlePage/news/detail/News/single-title
```

I am not even sure whether it is a Realurl or a News issue.
In the former case, do I need to define valueMap for postVarSets? How
do I do that?

TYPO3 6.2.13
News 3.2.2 
Realurl 1.13.4 
sr_language_menu 6.0.7

cheers
mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with realurl 1.x but it can be changed in realurl 2.x. You can write a feature request here: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues

RealURL 2.0 is expected to arrive to TER soon. It is already operational except for mount point support and BE module. BE module is in the active development right now.

**Edit (March 01, 2016):** this is now possible with RealURL 2.x. Basically you create a copy of your configuration and give it another name. Normally you have `_DEFAULT`, now you do something like `_lang1`. Than you use `_DOMAINS` to say that your L=1 should use `_lang1`:

`'_DOMAINS' => array(
        'encode' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'value' => 0,
                'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'value' => 1,
                'useConfiguration' => '_lang1',
            )
        ),`

In your `_lang1` you define a different prefix for a postVarSet.

That's all.

Comment: Perfect! I'll update my project sometime in a couple of weeks, and report. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if you didn't figure it out by the bottom of this: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/3.0.0/Main/Administration/Realurl/Index.html

Comment: I'll look at it, and report.

Comment: Vlatko: I did not figured out :-(. If you know how to do, please let me know. I appreciate